# Obtaining Keras Model Configuration

Tags: java, keras, deeplearning4j

Importing the Keras MobileNet V2 HDF5 file (obtained [here](https://github.com/JonathanCMitchell/mobilenet_v2_keras/releases)) with DL4J in Java throws the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.exceptions.InvalidKerasConfigurationException: Model configuration attribute missing from myfile.h5 archive.. For more information, see http://deeplearning4j.org/model-import-keras.`

I figure, I only downloaded the weights and not the model's structure.

I wish I could just download the needed file (some json I suppose), however, as I have searched a lot for it, guess it isn't out there. Additionally, I have no experience in creating such definitions myself. Also, Python is new to me.

How would you suggest I proceed to get any MobileNet version running for DL4J?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you file an issue on the deeplearning4j repo : https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues with the file you are trying to use? it's hard to tell what your problem is even coming from. Note: *uploading is important* we need a file.

Comment: Thanks @AdamGibson, I have submitted an issue on the repo page

Comment: @Henry Where exactly did you post the issue?

Comment: @herrtim There's actually two issues I created. The more recent issue (https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/issues/6171) references the original one. Unfortunately, no progress so far.